# How to utilize the button click event from all buttons to call a function?

Tags: vb.net

Let me explain further.  Let's say I have 20 buttons on a form, and in the all of the button's click event I want to call a specific function, instead of placing the calling to that function in each click event, is there a way to call it from any of the click events without having to place the code in each click event?

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If WinForms: In the IDE select all buttons you are working with then add a Click event. If any of the buttons have a click event already it will fire as well. No guarantee as to firing order. (A variation on the answer (Blue Dog) you accepted that avoids a bunch of typing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just add the click event for each button to the end of the `Handles` clause.

```
Private Sub My_Sub(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of buttons or a dynamic number of buttons, you could use a recursive method to add the same event handler for each. This will take care of all buttons, even those inside group boxes or other containers.

First, create the method you want each button click to call.

```
Private Sub bt_ButtonClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
  '
  ' Your code goes here
  '
End Sub
```

Second, create a method to recursively find all the button controls and add the event handler.

```
Private Sub AddEventHandler(RootControl As Control)
  For Each c As Control In RootControl
    If c.HasChildren Then
      AddEventHandler(c)
    End If
    If TypeOf c Is Button Then
      AddHandler c.Click, AddressOf bt_ButtonClick
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Lastly, in your form load event, add this line:

```
AddEventHandler(Me)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wire the one sub to the click event for every button.

```
Private Sub AnyButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: so does this automatically get generated when any of the buttons get clicked?

Comment: Does the sub get created when the button is clicked? No. You create it but the buttons fire the event, running whatever code you put in the sub.